# override bootstrap 4 .btn-link with underline transition

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to override bootstrap 4's `.btn-link` and add an effect to it when the mouse hovers over the link, a line moving from left to right transitions below it.

For the most part, its working. but it gets messed up when it's a button with a dropdown like this

```
<button class="btn btn-link shadow-none text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="price-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            price
```

the dropdown arrow is shown below the text. how would I fix this? thanks

here is my CSS

```
  .btn-link {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .btn-link,
  .btn-link:active,
  .btn-link:focus,
  .btn-link:hover {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .btn-link::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
  }
  .btn-link::after {
    top: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0%;
    left: 5%;
    background-color: rgb(41, 185, 153, 0.6);
    transition: 0.5s ease all 0s;
  }
  .btn-link:hover:after {
    width: 90%;
    transition: 0.3s ease all;
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

I changed `::after` to `::before` but now the accordion image is not aligned right

https://jsfiddle.net/2ud7nqy0/

Comment: _“the dropdown arrow is shown below the text”_ - not really, your custom line is. The dropdown arrow was made using the `::after` pseudo element of the button, but now you have overridden that formatting with your own, replaced the arrow. Use `::before` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the animation to `::before`.

What is happening in your case?

You were applying the animation to `::after` pseudo element. The `btn-link` applies its arrow through the same pseudo elemnt with the below style.
[image]

So adding style to `::after` pseudo element will make style conflicts. So move the same to `::before` pseudo element.

```css
.btn-link {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-link,
.btn-link:active,
.btn-link:focus,
.btn-link:hover {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-link::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}

.btn-link::before {
  top: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 5%;
  background-color: rgb(41, 185, 153, 0.6);
  transition: 0.5s ease all 0s;
}

.btn-link:hover:before {
  width: 90%;
  transition: 0.3s ease all;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-link shadow-none text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="price-dropdown"
  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  price
</button>
```

**EDIT:** It is alwaws better to use a custom class for adding new styles. In your case your accordion is making use of the `:before` pseudo element. So our custom styles will break that layout. So instead of adding styles to `btn-link` class, add a new class say `btn-custom` andd add the custom styles to that.

Working example https://jsfiddle.net/esvj70ny/

Comment: works, but now my custom arrows in my accordion are messed up `section.answersFaqs button[aria-expanded="false"] .arrows {
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 right: 20px;
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 background-image: url(right-arrow-faq.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: contain;
 background-position: center center;
 z-index: 3;
 transform: rotate(0);
}
`
on this  
`<button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#faq1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">test<span class="arrows"></span></button>`

Comment: @Sala Please update the isssue with a fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2ud7nqy0/ the arrow used to be align on the right, now its above the text

Comment: @Sala It is alwaws better to use a custom class for adding new styles. In your case your accordion is making use of the `:before` pseudo element. So our custom styles will break that layout. So instead of adding styles to `btn-link` class, add a new class say `btn-custom` andd add the custom styles to that.. I have attached a working fiddle in my answer.